# How can I change the query format for arrays in API Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I use last version of API Platform, and I was wondering if I could change the way to handle arrays in query string.

Default behavior relies on PHP way to handle arrays :

```
/customers?cars[]=audi&cars[]=mercedes&cars[]=bmw
```

According to Swagger documentation : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/, it can handle different ways :

```
/users?id=3,4,5
/users?id=3|4|5
```

Can I use this format using API Platform? I didn't find anything in the options, I suppose I can "trick" using Events (`DeserializeListener` maybe).

Answer (score -1):

This input format seems supported by Swagger: the style name of the parameter is `deepObject`.

There are many ways to support multiple inputs in query because the query is in fact a simple string containing `var=value`, therefore you can imagine whatever you want since var may be duplicated. PHP use the array-style (or `deepObject`) approach by default, and this is fine.

API Platform as support for this kind of "multiple filter" query by default: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#search-filter

If you want to use the following approach: `/users?id=3|4|5`, you can define [a custom filter](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-filters) with ease and use the request directly to explode the `id` parameter and complete your query internally.